# Elasticsearch - Query document missing an array value

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to query my elasticsearch index in order to retrieve the documents that don't contain a specific value in an array. For instance, if my query is :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match_all": {}
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [],
            "should": []
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "sort": [],
    "facets": {}
}
```

And the dataset :

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "product__1434374235336",
                "_type": "product",
                "_id": "AU33Xeny0K4pKlL-a7sr",
                "_source": {
                    "interdictions": ["S0P","SK3"],
                    "code": "foo"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "product__1434374235336",
                "_type": "product",
                "_id": "AU33Xeny0K4pKlL-a7sr",
                "_source": {
                    "interdictions": ["S0P","S2V","SK3"],
                    "code": "bar"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The objective is to exclude each product that contains the `"S2V"` interdiction. I initially thought of using a `missing` `filter` :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match_all": {}
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [],
            "should": []
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "missing": {
            "terms": {
                "interdictions": [
                    "S2V"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "sort": [],
    "facets": {}
}
```

But elasticsearch fails to parse the query : `QueryParsingException[[product__1434374235336] [missing] filter does not support [interdictions]]; }]",`. I then tried with a `must_not` :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match_all": {}
                }
            ],
            "must_not" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "interdictions" : ["S2V"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10
}
```

But the output is incorrect since it returns a product with the `S2V` interdictions.

So... What is the correct way to do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: The answer from @Andrei Stefan make senses. BTW you can use `match` instead of `terms`, so the analyzer will be applied for `S2V` when querying. View more here (`Why doesn’t the term query match my document?`) : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (with **lowercase value** for the `terms` bool):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "terms": {
          "interdictions": [
            "s2v"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

Most probably, you have an analyzer (maybe the `standard` default one) that does lower case the terms, so in the ES index the value is indexed as `s2v`, `sk3` etc. And `terms` doesn't analyze the input value, it's using it as is (in your case with uppercase letters), so it will never match.